# Error al subir calculos realizados con Jquery a la Base de datos

Tags: php, jquery

Hago unos calculos en un formulario y se los asigno a un campo. Fuciona muy bien.

```
function CalculaFee() {
IngresoTotalAnual = parseInt($('#PMensual').val())+ (parseInt($('#PAnual').val())/12) + parseInt($('#PAdiMensual').val());

$('#FeeSelectoras').val(new Intl.NumberFormat("es-AR",{ maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(IngresoTotalAnual ));}
```

La función calcula bien y en un ejemplo muestra el valor: **77.180,23**
Pero en la base solo graba el numero **77.18**  .
La columna de la tabla es Decimal(8,2)
no se cual es el error

Comment: Es muy mala idea guardar los cálculos realizados en el navegador, el usuario puede modificarlos sin problema. Haz las validaciones necesarias, calcula nuevamente en el servidor y guarda solo si todo está bien.

Comment: Hago el calculo pero no permito que lo modifique, los resultados estan en un campo readonly y ademas los campos variables son select. igual eso esta mal decis vos?

Comment: Haz clic con botón derecho en uno de los `select`, selecciona 'Inspeccionar elemento' y trata de modificar los valores de cada opción. ¿Se puede? Tal vez tú no lo permitas, pero el navegador sí, por eso es que tienes que validar todas las entradas del usuario.

Comment: Ah comprendo, igual al salir, via php controlo el valor de los select que estén en rango, no obstante te comprendo.. gracias. No obstante este tema aun no lo pude resolver...

Comment: La respuesta de @Alejandro es correcta si solo vas a guardar el dato tal como viene del formulario. No digo que dejes de hacer los cálculos en el navegador, simplemente que hagas las validaciones correspondientes en el servidor y, por cierto, para poder resolver el problema necesitas mostrar el código PHP con el que guardas los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que los separadores de decimales en la base de datos es el punto `.` deberías sustituir el punto por vacío y la coma por el punto
de manera que te quede así `77180.23`